# Maintain $cookies/$cookieStore in Angular ui-router after reloading from browser

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Problem:

After reloading a page using a browser I lose my $cookies/$cookieStore that were set on a my page. What i want is to access those $cookies/$cookieStore values.

My guess is that ui-router loses state when reloading from browser but I am confused because the $cookies were already set on the browser before the reloading happens.